# How to download Django media file uploaded using Django storages?

Tags: django, python-django-storages

I have successfully stored a Word document to S3 using Django-storages.

```
class Document(TitleSlugDescriptionModel, TimeStampedModel):
    document = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
```

Now in celery task, I need to download this file again for further processing in the worker.

Do I need to read the file from URL and then create the local copy explicitly or is there any way to create local copy using Django-storages?

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file directly in Django using the read method as in
`document.read()`
this will output binary which you can save to a file using

```
f=open(filename, 'wb')
f.write(document.read())
f.close
```

You can also generate URLs to the file on S3 as well. More info on both in the docs: https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html